# How to remove existing <option> from a <select> dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The values I checked in checkboxes should appear in the dropdown list.

Every time I select a new value, previous values should be cleared from the dropdown list, and only the new selected values should be displayed.

But now, new values are displayed along with the previous values.

Below is the code I currently have.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <select id="select-client" name="client">
    <option value="-1">-select-</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var selectedKnowledgeBaseArray = [];

  $("#clientuser").on('click', function() {

    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
      selectedKnowledgeBaseArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "client_user_map.json",
      processData: true,
      data: {
        selectedKnowledgeBaseArray: selectedKnowledgeBaseArray
      },
      traditional: true,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $("#clntusrmap").show();
        $('#clntusrmap').find('input:text').val('');
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        buildSortedData(data);
      }
    });

    function buildSortedData(data) {
      if (data[0].length > 0) {
        var select = document.getElementById("select-client");
        for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
          var option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = option.value = data[0][i];
          console.log(data[0][i]);
          select.add(option, i + 1);
          $('.deleteMeetingClose').on("click", function() {
            var select = document.getElementById("select-client");
            $('select').empty();
          });
        }
      }
    }

  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: html code is:<select id="select-client" name = "client">
            <option value="-1">-select-</option>
        </select>

Comment: try  $('select').html(''); instead of $('select').empty();

Comment: Add the relevant HTML code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that what you mentioned in the question is run when `#clientuser` is clicked. So, the problem is the array `selectedKnowledgeBaseArray` which is shared among the functions.

Whenever you click on `#clientuser`, the checked elements of `input[type=checkbox]:checked` selector are appended in `selectedKnowledgeBaseArray`, and then this array is passed to the AJAX call.

I'm not sure what does the AJAX call return, but if it returns the elements which you've passed, the function `buildSortedData` will receive them and try to append those to your select box using `select.add(option, i + 1);`.

Also beware that you're calling the following snippet in loop

```
$('.deleteMeetingClose').on("click", function() {
  var select = document.getElementById("select-client");
  $('select').empty();
});
```

This binds multiple click events on all the elements matched by `.deleteMeetingClose`, and if not yet, this will create problem in future for sure.

Comment: what is the solution for it?

Comment: @KomalJain solution for what?

Answer (score 0):

give your select option in html an ID or class name like in the below code

```
<select id="select-choice">
</select>
```

and in jQuery write

```
 /*if it is given an id*/
$('#select-choice").empty()
/*else if it is given a class name then*/
 $('.select-choice').empty()
```

this code had help me, hope it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try $(select).empty(); instead of $('select').empty();

Or instead of:

```
var select = document.getElementById("select-client");
$('select').empty();
```

you can use the jquery selector:

```
$("#select-client").empty();
```